# Javascript Check if number = variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var Period =1;

        if(Period==1){
            document.getElementById("Main").style.backgroundImage = "url('Main_Background_Grass_1.png')";
        }
```

For some reason this wont work. The image location is correct but im sure there is something wrong.

im pretty new to javascript

heres more code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var Knowledge = 0;
        var Period =1;

        if(Period==1){
            document.getElementById("Main").style.backgroundImage = "url('Main_Background_Grass_1.png')";
        }

</script>

<div id="Main">

    <div id="Toolbar">
        Oh noes! Something Went Wrong
    </div>
</div>
```

the image wont show up at all

Comment: Please define "wont work". Any errors in the console? Background image doesn't appear? A wrong image appears? Something else?

Comment: yea its the exact ID and background image dosen't appear

Comment: Browsers have consoles that display error messages. In chrome, try Ctrl+J. In Firefox, Ctrl+K.

Comment: How about the console, can you see any error messages?

Comment: Where is the code placed? My bet is it's in the head

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. yes Main_Background_Grass_1.png is in same file

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/TmdiiwL.png

Comment: Then this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element isn't found at the time you call your function, place the javascript right before the closing body tag

```
<div id="Main">

    <div id="Toolbar">
        Oh noes! Something Went Wrong
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var Knowledge = 0;
        var Period =1;

        if(Period==1){
            document.getElementById("Main").style.backgroundImage = "url('Main_Background_Grass_1.png')";
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`
That's because the element wasn't loaded yet. There are two ways to make sure a code runs only when a page is ready. One is to put the code at the bottom of the body, so the page has already been loaded. The other is to put it in an event listener for the window load event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {

  // code goes here

  });
</script>
```

Which one is the best practice? That's an eternal debate. I prefer the listener so that the code is all at the top, but many would disagree.